# Define constructor for newtype

Tags: haskell, constructor, newtype

I have a type

```
class IntegerAsType a where
  value :: a -> Integer

data T5
instance IntegerAsType T5 where value _ = 5

newtype (Num a, IntegerAsType n) => PolyRing a n = PolyRing [a]
```

I've looked around for a way to specify the constructor for the newtype. I realize there can only be one, but I don't see why I can specify what it is.

For example, I might want to only take the first three elements of the argument to the `PolyRing` value constructor.

I tried adding using a `where` clause at the end of the newtype declaration, but that didn't compile.

I also tried:

```
(PolyRing xs) = PolyRing [2, 3, 5, 7]
```

as a toy example. What I think this should do is ignore the argument to the value constructor and always have the value `[2,3,5,7]`. The code compiles, but my "custom" constructor has no effect.

Is it possible to specify the constructor for a newtype?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You're specifying the constructor when you do `newtype PolyRing a n = PolyRing [a]`. If you want to call the constructor something else do `newtype PolyRing a n = SomethingElse [a]`.

Comment: I don't want to just rename it, I want to *do* something during the construction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a [Smart constructor](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Smart_constructors).

`PolyRing`'s basic capitalized constructor cannot be overloaded.  But what you can do is this:

```
polyRing :: (Num a, IntegerAsType n) => [a] -> PolyRing a n
polyRing = PolyRing . take 3
```

Or, even better:

```
polyRing :: (Num a, IntegerAsType n) => [a] -> Maybe (PolyRing a n)
polyRing (a:b:c:_) = Just $ PolyRing [a, b, c]
polyRing _         = Nothing
```

To prevent someone from using the `PolyRing` constructor directly, your module export declaration at the top of the file could look like this:

```
module PolyRing (
 PolyRing (), -- Export the PolyRing type but not constructor
 polyRing     -- Your smart constructor
) where
```

In OO, the unit of encapsulation is the class, but in Haskell, it's the module.